# Determine all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ so that a series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

How do I determine all

$a\in\mathbb{R}$

for a series

$\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot \frac{a^n}{n}$

so that the series converges?

I know that the series converges for

$a=1$

And I  think that it diverges for every $a >1 $ since it diverges to $\infty$.

But how do I determine all   $a$   to make the series convergent?

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ratio test; notice that the ratio between successive terms is $\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{a^{n}}{n}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot a$ which converges to $a$ as $n$ gets large. You can use this to argue that the series converges for all $a\in (1,-1)$ and diverges for $|a|>1$. This leaves the case of $a=1$ which you have already resolved and $a=-1$, which should be a familiar series.

Comment: no, it converge to $0$ if $|a|<1$. (not to $a$)

Comment: @idm That is not true. The term $\frac{n+1}n=1+\frac{1}n$ goes to $1$ as $n$ gets large, and $a$ is constant. Ergo, the limit of $\frac{n+1}n \cdot a$ as $n$ gets large is $1\cdot a = a$. You can check this numerically if you desire. Maybe you're thinking that the *terms* go to zero, which they do, but the *ratios* between successive ones does not.

Comment: I thought that you conclude that $\frac{a^n}{n}\to a$ if $\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{a^n}{n}}\to a$. It's my false, sorry for that (I'm not english, that's why I sometimes make mistakes in the comprehension). Anyway, your proof is correct and I canceled my downvote.

Comment: @idm Oh, I see what you're thinking; my argument is that since the ratio converges to a value in $(-1,1)$, the sum must converge too - but I don't specify to what. (Also, I never really talked about the behavior of $\frac{a^n}n$ aside from its common ratio - a subtle distinction to make, which might clarify exactly my post's meaning, is that "series" generally means "sequence of partial sums" - that is, I was referring to the partial sums, not to the sequence $\frac{a^n}n$ itself)

Comment: @Meelo I got it but what exactly is the argumentation for $(-1{,}1)$ ?

Comment: @Viktor That's the interval where $|a|<1$. The point there is that, if for sufficiently large $n$, the ratio of the absolute values of the terms is decreasing by a constant factor less than one, then the absolute value of the sequence being summed is bounded above by a geometric series $c \cdot r^n$ for some $c$ and $r<1$ - and since geometric series converge, so must any series which is bounded by one.

Comment: Alright now everything's clear :) Thank you for the fast answer !